# Count tags of a specific type in an html document and display it as a number using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can you simply create a counter that counts a specific type of element in an html and displays the count in a div. For example, count the `li` and display the number:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>

<div class="counter">5</div>
```

Comment: @AndrewL. Counting the number li's within the html and have the counter show the overall count :)

Comment: You can break your question down into two parts. The first is, how do I **find** all the tags of a specific type? The second is, how do I get its length. For the first question, a google search for "find all tags of certain type in html javascript" returned the answer (use `getElementsByTagName`) as the first result. Of course, to Google successfully you'd have to use proper terminology, and understand the difference between classes and tags, etc. Once you know how to find the list of tags, it's a quick step to using `.length` on it to find the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number by using `querySelectorAll` (or `getElementsByTagName`) and getting the length property of the returned list of elements:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("counter")[0].textContent = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li").length;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<div class="counter"></div>
```

This uses pure JavaScript to get the number of `li`s and inserts them into the `div`. Let me break it down:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("counter")[0]
```

Get's the *first* `div` with class name `counter`. Next, it access its `textContent` property, which is the inner text of the element. It then reassigns that to:

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li").length
```

That searches the document for all elements with the tag `li` which are **immediate children of `ul` elements**. It then get's the length of the returned list of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, exactly what I needed and works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @stepho no problem, if you need anything else, feel free to ask :)